# CoreMIDI Manufacturer Presets

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, audio, core-audio, coremidi

I built a virtual MIDI controller with CoreMIDI and would like to import manufacturer presets for ControlChange (i.e. cc value, associated effect name with cc number, preset name, etc.).  Is there a simple way to do this or do I need to hard code this information?  I have found the MIDI manufacturer IDs on the MMA website, can this be used to obtain specific data in virtual instruments? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

MIDI has never provided a means of self-describing.

There have been efforts to standardise MIDI parameter sets, such as [General MIDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_MIDI), and vendor standards such as [Yamaha XG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamaha_XG) and [Roland GS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roland_GS), but even amongst instruments from the same vendor, the control sets were not consistent.  Perhaps not surprising, as for this to work, the samples data used for the voices would need to be standardised as well - and of course, this is the differentiator between instruments.

What has tended to happen is that manufacturers have made heavy use of `SYSEX` for control functions in a way that is entirely non-standardized (particularly amongst their *own* products).

Building any kind of generalised MIDI editor requires you to create a mapping table for each device you intend to control describing the controls and their MIDI mapping.  You'll usually find a substantial MIDI implementation chart in the user manual of each instrument with the data.

Comment: I thought this might be the case, a guys gotta dream though.  Thanks for you response.

Comment: This [bunch](http://www.squest.com./Distrib/Contact.html) have a commercial product that pretty much does what you describe.   There are lots of other retarded problems that need solving, such as maximum `SYSEX` block-sizes and inter-block delays.  And devices whose firmware crashes when you send too much data at it too fast.  Yes, seriously.  MIDI is really not fit for this purpose and needs to go away fast.  But probably won't.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2020, this will probably be best accomplished with MIDI Capability Inquiry. Parameter recall can be accomplished with MIDI-CI Property Exchange.